# Why does strcat_s crash if writing over the bound of a char array?

Tags: c++

I know, there are already many posts about this topic, but I didn't find anything satisfiying. Even google was not my friend.

So, first my code:

```
    void secureCat() {
        const int BUFFERSIZE = 5;
        char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];

        strcpy_s (buffer, BUFFERSIZE, "01");
        cout << "1, buffer=" << buffer << endl;

        errno_t rc = 0;

        // still works
        rc = strcat_s(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, "2"); 

        cout << (rc == 0 ? "yippee" : "oh noooo") << endl;
        cout << "2, buffer=" << buffer << endl;

        // and now the crashing line
        rc = strcat_s(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, "345"); 

        cout << (rc == 0 ? "yippee" : "oh noooo") << endl;
        cout << "3, buffer=" << buffer << endl;
    }
```

I played with this code on Windows with MS VS 2010 and experienced the following:

The **first** call of strcat_s works fine, which is clear for me because the size of the new string (`"01"` + `"2"` + `NUL` character) is smaller then the buffer size.

But why does the **second** call crash, when the buffer size is exceeded? As far as I understand the MSDN, I should get an error code back and the buffer should only have the NUL character.
The behavior in the example is more like that of strcat: I overwrite my own code, so it crashes.

BTW: I know, that there are other ways to concatenate strings and that it's a better style to do checks before it. So this is more for a pure interest to look behind the scenes.

Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [MSDN documentation for `strcat_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d45bbxx4.aspx) reads:

> [...] if the destination string is too small, the invalid parameter handler 
>   is invoked, as described in [Parameter Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksazx244.aspx).

If you follow the [Parameter Validation link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksazx244.aspx), you can read (emphasis mine):

> **Invalid Parameter Handler Routine**
>
> [...] ***The default invalid parameter invokes Watson crash reporting, which causes the application to crash*** and asks the user if they want to load the crash dump to Microsoft for analysis. In Debug mode, an invalid parameter also results in a failed assertion.
>
> This behavior can be changed by using the function `_set_invalid_parameter_handler` to set the invalid parameter handler to your own function. [...]

---

As an alternative, you may want to consider the [`StringCchCat()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which returns an `HRESULT` equal to `STRSAFE_E_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` in case of destination buffer too small.

Comment: Great to know about  StringCchCat(). Made a comment on it at  [strcat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d45bbxx4(v=vs.100).aspx).